# Set parameter headers calling REST

Tags: objective-c, rest, http-headers

must set the parameters in REST calls for authentication.
Use this code

```
NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

    parameters[@"nst_code"] = NST_CODE;
    parameters[@"nst_id"] = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"nst_id"];
    parameters[@"api_key"] = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"api_key"];
```

as an indication?

Comment: So, what's the problem or question?

Comment: What is the HTTP method? GET, POST? Do you have to pass the parameters in the query or in body? JSON, www-form-url-encoded?